# SQL Selecting MIN value from a field in a subquery to return 1 record

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

How do I select one record from my subquery with the MIN value in the ORDER_NO field?

```
SELECT STATE_CODE,
  PROJECT_ID,
  MIN(ORDER_NO) AS ORDER_NO,
  TEST_SECTION
FROM
  (SELECT STATE_CODE,
    PROJECT_ID,
    ORDER_NO,
    RECORD_STATUS,
    TEST_SECTION,
    SECTION_START,
    SECTION_END,
    SECTION_CUT_FILL,
    DIRECTION_OF_TRAVEL,
    CASE
      WHEN DIRECTION_OF_TRAVEL=LEAD(DIRECTION_OF_TRAVEL) OVER (ORDER BY STATE_CODE,PROJECT_ID,ORDER_NO)
      OR DIRECTION_OF_TRAVEL  =LAG(DIRECTION_OF_TRAVEL) OVER (ORDER BY STATE_CODE,PROJECT_ID,ORDER_NO)
      THEN 'MAIN DIRECTION'
      ELSE 'OPPOSITE DIRECTION'
    END AS "DIRECTION"
  FROM SPS_PROJECT_STATIONS
  WHERE STATE_CODE=24
  AND PROJECT_ID LIKE 'A3%%'
  AND SUBSTR(TEST_SECTION,3,2)=SUBSTR(PROJECT_ID,1,2)
  )
GROUP BY STATE_CODE,
  PROJECT_ID;
```

Here are the results from the subquery:

```
| STATE_CODE | PROJECT_ID | ORDER_NO | RECORD_STATUS | TEST_SECTION | SECTION_START | SECTION_END | SECTION_CUT_FILL | DIRECTION_OF_TRAVEL | DIRECTION      |
|:----------:|------------|----------|---------------|--------------|---------------|-------------|------------------|---------------------|----------------|
| 24         | A300       | 2        | E             | 24A310       | 320           | 472         | 3                | 1                   | MAIN DIRECTION |
| 24         | A300       | 3        | E             | 24A330       | 533           | 686         | 3                | 1                   | MAIN DIRECTION |
| 24         | A300       | 4        | E             | 24A320       | 747           | 899         | 2                | 1                   | MAIN DIRECTION |
| 24         | A300       | 5        | E             | 24A340       | 960           | 1113        | 3                | 1                   | MAIN DIRECTION |
| 24         | A300       | 6        | E             | 24A350       | 1173          | 1325        | 1                | 1                   | MAIN DIRECTION |
| 24         | A300       | 7        | E             | 24A311       | 1386          | 1539        | 2                | 1                   | MAIN DIRECTION |
| 24         | A300       | 8        | E             | 24A331       | 1584          | 1736        | 1                | 1                   | MAIN DIRECTION |
```

Comment: Please add that to your question. It is impossible to read it in a comment.

Comment: What is the current issue?  Do you only want one record from your current results?  Or are you getting the wrong results?

Comment: I'm not sure how to add my subquery results on the question, the table is a mess when I paste it on there.

Comment: Yes, only one record from the results.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want a single row from this query in which the ORDER_NO is the MIN ORDER_NO of your set.

```
SELECT TOP 1 STATE_CODE,
  PROJECT_ID,
  ORDER_NO,
  TEST_SECTION
FROM (...)

ORDER BY ORDER_NO;
```

Top 1 will get only one row, and by ordering by ORDER_NO you are ensuring your single row return set is the one containing the MIN ORDER_NO

Comment: I guess I didn't specify...Oracle SQLPlus
I'm new to this...sorry!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work...unless someone has a better idea

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT STATE_CODE,
PROJECT_ID,
ORDER_NO,
RECORD_STATUS,
TEST_SECTION,
SECTION_START,
SECTION_END,
SECTION_CUT_FILL,
DIRECTION_OF_TRAVEL,
DIRECTION,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY STATE_CODE,PROJECT_ID ORDER BY STATE_CODE,PROJECT_ID,ORDER_NO) AS "ROW NUMBER"
FROM
(SELECT STATE_CODE,
  PROJECT_ID,
  ORDER_NO,
  RECORD_STATUS,
  TEST_SECTION,
  SECTION_START,
  SECTION_END,
  SECTION_CUT_FILL,
  DIRECTION_OF_TRAVEL,
  CASE
    WHEN DIRECTION_OF_TRAVEL=LEAD(DIRECTION_OF_TRAVEL) OVER (ORDER BY STATE_CODE,PROJECT_ID,ORDER_NO)
    OR DIRECTION_OF_TRAVEL  =LAG(DIRECTION_OF_TRAVEL) OVER (ORDER BY STATE_CODE,PROJECT_ID,ORDER_NO)
    THEN 'MAIN DIRECTION'
    ELSE 'OPPOSITE DIRECTION'
  END AS "DIRECTION"
FROM SPS_PROJECT_STATIONS
WHERE STATE_CODE=24
AND PROJECT_ID LIKE 'A3%%'
AND SUBSTR(TEST_SECTION,3,2)=SUBSTR(PROJECT_ID,1,2)
ORDER BY STATE_CODE,
  PROJECT_ID,
  ORDER_NO
)
WHERE DIRECTION='MAIN DIRECTION'
)
WHERE "ROW NUMBER"=1;
```